# Non linear Recursion demonstration

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, arithmetic, recursion

I wrote a code to find the $ \lim_{n \to ∞} F_n \ $ where $a > 0$ and $F_n$ is defined as:
$$F_0=x_0$$
$$F_{n+1}=0.5(F_n+\frac{a}{F_n})$$

By analysing the output of the code and trying different values for $a$, I found out that the  $ \lim_{n \to ∞} F_n = a^{0.5}\ $

I want to understand why. Can someone help me with a small demonstration.
Also, I would appreciate if someone give me the correct term to research about this particular type of recursion for my further readings.

Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: Hint: solve the equation $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)$ for $x$.

Comment: So we can assume that the sequence converge, if so, at large number of n, Fn and Fn+1 are the same, so we just solve for Fn, in your case you substituted it by x, and we got sqrt(a) and -sqrt(a). So we choose the positive answer. Why ?

Comment: Also, why did we assume that the sequence converges? How can we demonstrate that too ? Or we just assume first and if the equation has a root, then that's the proof ?

Comment: This is one of the most ancient pieces of mathematics we know! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite
$$F_{n+1}=\frac 12 \left(F_n+\frac{a}{F_n}  \right)=F_n-\frac 12 \left(F_n-\frac{a}{F_n}  \right)=F_n-\frac{F_n^2-a}{2 F_n }$$ This is also [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) iterative scheme for solving $F^2=a$ starting with $F_0$.